# touch keyboard show property on windows 8 metro app

Tags: wpf, windows, microsoft-metro

I am working on a windows 8 app, where in i have a popup dialog on left bottom of the screen, if the touch keyboard is shown the popup is not visible, is there a property to determine if the keyboard is shown, to move the popup up if the touch keyboard is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this blog post: [Tips and Tricks for C# Metro developers: Handling the virtual keyboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2012/07/09/tips-and-tricks-for-c-metro-developers-handling-the-virtual-keyboard.aspx)

You can use `InputPane`'s `Showing` & `Hiding` events. Here `flyout` is the `Popup` object.

```
int flyoutOffset = 0;
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing += (s, args) =>
{
    flyoutOffset = (int)args.OccludedRect.Height;
    flyout.VerticalOffset -= flyoutOffset;
};
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Hiding += (s, args) =>
{
    flyout.VerticalOffset += flyoutOffset;
};
```